# PC Crash - Seemingly Random

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, motherboard, bios

Of recent times, I replaced my motherboard to a [Gigabyte H97M](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-H97M-D3H-rev-10) with an I[ntel i7 4790k](https://ark.intel.com/products/80807/Intel-Core-i7-4790K-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-4_40-GHz), and a [1070 Founders Edition](https://www.msi.com/Graphics-card/GeForce-GTX-1070-Founders-Edition.html). Running Windows 10, becoming more frequent I am experiencing issues wherein the PC will (seemingly) randomly crash; screens turn off (although I have discord still running for a time), and the fans all seem to "kick into overdrive".

Using PrecisionX, I have output some sample data here:

[image: Sample Data]

For reference, the highest value this program was recording for temperature was 43 degrees, and power at 49W.

If I perform the same with a CPU test, the data is rather the same however I am seeing values of load percentile above 90% utilization; and I do notice the CPU fan is the first to kick into overdrive, yet all temps are below 75 degrees. In the motherboards BIOS, I am seeing alarms set for >95% utilization on the CPU, but am yet to hit this measurement.

The drivers I have are direct from manufacturer, and the BIOS is flashed to the latest version. I do plan on pulling the PC apart on the weekend to place my old Z97-X Gaming 7 motherboard in, and will re-apply thermal paste and whatnot to it, to see if this alleviates any issues.

According to "Task Manager" and "Performance Monitor", there are no applications that seemingly use excessive amounts of CPU (as of writing this Q, I have 21 tabs on Chrome, excel, discord, steam and LoL running), and I am unsure of any applicant that can read process using CPU (working on scripting it now) in real-time either.

How would you go about troubleshooting this?

- [EVGA Home Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qy8O0.png)
- [EVGA Monitoring Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XV04W.png)
- [Fan Curve Profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qy8O0.png)

Further information on the current PC is as follows:

- [Memory Information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQmfE.png)
- [Graphics Information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsT7F.png)
- [CPU information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H26ML.png)

I am using an Antec 850W Modular PSU (under 1 year old), and have 4x SSDs and 5x 24" fans running on the system, not sure total power consumption.

BurnIn Test Results:

[image: Results]

Comment: I'd check RAM slots and connectors first, maybe one memory module is faulty also and doesn't return proper data on read, try with only one module at a time if possible to see if the problem persist. Then try another slot, this may help finding the root cause.

Comment: Are there any events pertaining to VPU recovery in the Event Viewer?

Comment: I always recommend looking at capacitors, and this time I'm going to suggest a PSU swap/test.  How old is your PSU, what's the wattage, and how much power is your complete system pulling (fans, drives, etc. included)?  Are you using a UPS, and if so, how old is it?

Comment: @Tensibai I have just done a reseat of the RAM, and will first do a memtest, then perform the mentioned.

Comment: @Yorik Where wuld "VPU" events be stored? System? Doing a search now and am yielding no records.

Comment: @computercarguy I have added some more information on PSU, peripherals etc. How would you suggest I identify my power draw on the PC? I have a 450W PSU but feel as though this is not enough to run the entire system and give valid results.

Comment: Based on the specs you posted, and some basic guessing I did for specs not posted, I looked at https://outervision.com to calculate the power consumption.  You might want to verify my findings, but your 850W PSU should be just fine, and since it's less than 1 year old, it shouldn't have degraded enough to matter yet.  Without physically testing it myself, I'm not sure of anything except the crash is killing the fan controllers, allowing them to just spin at top speed until it shuts off completely.  That *may* mean it's a mobo issue.